# How to build a TCP connection with multiple clients, c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, tcp

I am trying to build a TCP server on windows with c++. I know that if I want to communicate with all clients, I can use threads. One thread handles one client. I am wondering is there any other method to handle this task, for example:

```
std::vector<SOCKET> clients;
while(clients.size() < 1024){
    SOCKET ss = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
    clients.push_back(ss);
}

while(true){
    SOCKET speckingClient = Function(clients);
    iResult = recv(speckingClient, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
    // the rest of the function...
}
```

The above code cannot be run but hopefully showing what I am looking for.

Comment: Learn about client-server architecture first and then socket handling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is a better technique.

The preferred method is to use `select()` (or more likely one of its replacements). Optionally with a thread pool.

`select()` allows you wait for input on multiple ports simultaneously. When input is available (or space is available for write) select returns allowing you to processes all available inputs/outputs on all ports.

You should look up the the [C10K](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html) problem on google. You will find lots of articles on how to write a server that handles many incoming client requests.

Comment: You should also note that the so-called C10K problem itself has been considered obsolete for some years.

Comment: @EJP: Its been some years since I looked at it, so I actually did not realize that. Do you have any alternative references we should look at?